# Trouble running something from the console

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I just installed Ubuntu on my pc and I have trouble running my code. I installed eclipse and the latest java jdk. I can compile the with the following command:
javac -cp .:Downloads/jsoup1.8.2.jar workspace/Währungsrechner/src/Crawl.java
but when I try to run it by using the command:
java -cp .:Downloads/jsoup1.8.2.jar workspace/Währungsrechner/src/Crawl
it says that the Class cannot be found and yes I have a method called public static void main(String args[]).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specifiy the class to run when executing the command.

Use `java -cp . Downloads/jsoup1.8.2.jar workspace/Währungsrechner/src/Crawl`.

By the way, specifying "-cp ." is unnecessary when running a class, so you can just use `java Downloads/jsoup1.8.2.jar workspace/Währungsrechner/src/Crawl`

Comment: I already tried that. I have used ubuntu before and I never had to write .java after the class name when wanting to run something.

Comment: I can compile it but I can't run it.

Comment: @YoLo Oh sorry, I just noticed that you weren't using "javac" in the second command. I'll edit my answer.